# Scrolled event of UICollectionView not fired in Xamarin.IOS

Tags: ios, scroll, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

I am developing an app in Xamarin.IOS. 
I've implement below code in my view controller

```
collectionView.Scrolled += Collection_Scrolled;
void Collection_Scrolled(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    topButton.hidden = false;    
}
```

But when I scroll the collection view, this function Collection_Scrolled is not called. I was doing same thing in UIScrollView and it worked good and UICollectionView is subclass of UIScrollView so I think it should work.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found an issue.

I was setting custom DataSource to collection view and implementing IUICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.

I am not supposed to mix Objective-C delegates with C# events!
It just was problem.

So I overrided Scrolled function in DataSource and it worked!

Hope this answer will help others!